# Laravel: Mollie - webhook failed with status code 500

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, mollie

I'm using the mollie developer setup to simulate payment offers. I've followed a tutorial by my teacher and he hasn't any problems. So what is going on?

Because Mollie is an online service, I'm using Ngrok to create a tunnel for the webhook and my localhost. I'll post my code below but know that I wrote a Log which gave as response:

> [2022-07-26 18:22:54] local.ERROR: Method App\Http\Controllers\webHookController::handle does not exist. {"exception":"[object] (BadMethodCallException(code: 0): Method App\Http\Controllers\webHookController::handle does not exist. at C:\Users\stefv\SCHOOL\GENT\NMD\WEBDEV2\werkstuk---geboortelijst-Stef-Verniers\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php:68)

I have no clue what exact error this log is targeting so if anyone can point this out, it's much appreciated!

Because the webhook can't get to mollie my status inside my database can't be changed so it's on 'pending' forever...

So I'm looking for a way to fix the error so my webhook can reach Mollie and my payment is accepted so the payment status in my database can change to 'paid'.

This is my code:
My Controller which sets up Mollie:

```
public function additional(Request $r)
{
    $articles = Article::all();
    $categories = Category::all();
    $websites = Website::all();
    $session_id = request()->session()->getId();
    $cartItems = Cart::session($session_id)->getContent();
    $cartTotal = Cart::session($session_id)->getTotal();
    $r->session()->put('cusnaam', 'Cas');
    $r->session()->put('tel', 'Tel');
    $r->session()->put('email', 'Email');
    $r->session()->put('pb', 'pb');

    return view('customer-info', compact('articles', 'categories', 'websites', 'cartItems', 'cartTotal'));
}

public function checkout(Request $r) 
{

    $session_id = request()->session()->getId();
    $cartTotal = Cart::session($session_id)->getTotal();

    $order = new Order();
    $order->name = $r->input('Cus');
    $order->note = $r->input('pb');
    $order->total = $cartTotal;
    $order->status = 'pending';

    $order->save();


    $mollie = new \Mollie\Api\MollieApiClient();
    $mollie->setApiKey("test_6vGchNb62gynePtcsNsbm8dartsmjU");
    $mollie->methods->allAvailable();

    $session_id = request()->session()->getId();
    $cartItems = Cart::session($session_id)->getContent();
    $valuta = number_format($cartTotal, 2);

    
    $webhookUrl = route('webhooks.mollie');

    if(App::environment('local')) {
       $webhookUrl = 'https://5d25-84-199-205-243.eu.ngrok.io/webhooks/mollie';
    };

    $payment = Mollie::api()->payments->create([
        "amount" => [
            "currency" => "EUR",
            "value" => $valuta // You must send the correct number of decimals, thus we enforce the use of strings
        ],
        "description" => "Bestelling op dag " . date('d-m-Y h:i'),
        "redirectUrl" => route('success'),
        "webhookUrl" => $webhookUrl,
        "metadata" => [
            "order_id" => $order->id,
            "order_name" => $order->name
        ],
    ]);

    return redirect($payment->getCheckoutUrl(), 303);

}

public function success()
{
    return view('succes');
}
```

And this is the controller that handles the webhook:

```
public function handleWebhookNotification(Request $request) 
{

    $payment = Mollie::api()->payments->get($request->id);
    $orderId = $payment->metadata->order_id;

    if ($payment->isPaid() && ! $payment->hasRefunds() && ! $payment->hasChargebacks()) {

        $order = Order::findOrFail($orderId);
        $order->status = 'paid';
        $order->save();

        Log::alert('tis in de cachoche');

    } elseif ($payment->isOpen()) {
        /*
         * The payment is open.
         */
    } elseif ($payment->isPending()) {
        /*
         * The payment is pending.
         */
    } elseif ($payment->isFailed()) {
        /*
         * The payment has failed.
         */
    } elseif ($payment->isExpired()) {
        /*
         * The payment is expired.
         */
    } elseif ($payment->isCanceled()) {
        /*
         * The payment has been canceled.
         */
    } elseif ($payment->hasRefunds()) {
        /*
         * The payment has been (partially) refunded.
         * The status of the payment is still "paid"
         */
    } elseif ($payment->hasChargebacks()) {
        /*
         * The payment has been (partially) charged back.
         * The status of the payment is still "paid"
         */
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Your error is saying that your class `webHookController` (that _should_ be `WebHookController` to comply with naming conventions) is missing a method called `handle`. Is there something in their documentation that says you need to define that method? Does it work if you rename `handleWebhookNotification` to just `handle`? For transparency, I haven't worked with Mollie before, but your error seems pretty self-explanatory to me.

Comment: As @TimLewis describes, the error tells you it cannot find the `handle` method on class `webHookController`. Two things that immediately stand out. First is that there is no `handle` method in your controller, but `handleWebhookNotification`. Either change the route definition or change `handleWebhookNotification` to `handle`. Second is that the controller in the error is named `webHookController. Shouldn't it be `WebHookController`?

Comment: @TimLewis Lewis. With the feedback you've provided. I've edited the name of the controller and took a look in my routes and I saw that I had a route to trigger the webhook that was connected to the handle class while in my controller I was using the handleWebhookNotification. So after I made the changes, IT WORKED!! Thank you guys!!

Comment: Excellent! I figured it would be something simple like that. Glad you got it sorted out 